# Bind background color to all textboxes

Tags: wpf, vb.net, data-binding, wpf-controls

Hey all I am new at WPF and was wondering if anyone would show me how to define a binding color so that I can add that same code to all my textboxes and only have to change one code instead of each individually?

My XAML code:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtBC_Copy" 
         materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Enter the items name that was scanned in" 
         Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}" 
         Margin="478,90,25,618" 
         FontSize="24" 
         Background="{Binding MyBackgroundColor}" 
         BorderBrush="#890C00FF" 
         FontWeight="Bold" 
         CaretBrush="#89000000" 
         BorderThickness="0,0,0,2" 
         Foreground="#DD000000" >
         <TextBox.SelectionBrush>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="#890C00FF" Opacity="0"/>
         </TextBox.SelectionBrush>
</TextBox>
```

As you can see above I already tried **Binding MyBackgroundColor**.

The code behind:

```
Private _myBackgroundColor As Color
Public Property MyBackgroundColor() As Color
    Get
        Return _myBackgroundColor
    End Get
    Set
        If Value <> _myBackgroundColor Then
            _myBackgroundColor = Value
        End If
    End Set
End Property

Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    MyBackgroundColor = Colors.Red
End Sub
```

Using both of those above, I run the app and I do not see a red background on the txtBC_Copy textbox.... What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type of `Background` is `Brush`, so, change your code like :

```
Private _myBackgroundColor As Brush
Public Property MyBackgroundColor() As Brush
    Get
        Return _myBackgroundColor
    End Get
    Set
        If Value <> _myBackgroundColor Then
            _myBackgroundColor = Value
        End If
    End Set
End Property

Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    MyBackgroundColor = Brushes.Red
End Sub
```